# Confused about the definitions of cofinite and cocountable topologies

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Note: $cc$ stands for "cocountable" and $cf$ stands for "cofinite".

Statement:

> (i) Any one-to-one map from $(\mathbb R, \tau_{cc})$ to $(\mathbb R, \tau_{cf})$ is continuous.

> (ii) Any continuous map from $(\mathbb R, \tau_{cf})$ to $(\mathbb R, \tau_{usual})$ is constant.

Proof:

> (i) Let $F$ be $\tau_{cf}$ closed. $\color{red}{\text{Then either $F = \mathbb R$ or $F$ is finite.}}$ Thus, in the first case, we have $F = \mathbb R \implies f^{-1}(F) = \mathbb R \implies  f^{-1}(F)$ is $\tau_{cc}$ closed and in the latter case, $f$ is $1-1$ and $f$ is finite $\implies f^{-1}(F)$ is finite $\implies f^{-1}(F)$ is countable $\implies \color{green}{\text{$f^{-1}(F)$ is $\tau_{cc}$ closed}}$. Hence $f$ is continuous.

> (ii) Suppose $g$ is not constant. Then exist $x, y \in \mathbb R$ s.t. $g(x) > g(y).$ Pick disjoint, open intervals $I, J$ in $\mathbb R$ s.t. $g(x) \in I, g(y) \in J$. Now $g^{-1}(I) \cap g^{-1}(J) = g^{-1}(I \cap J) = g^{-1}(\emptyset) = \emptyset$ and $x \in g^{1}(I), y \in g^{-1}(J)$, so $g^{-1}(I), g^{-1}(J)$ are nonempty, disjoint and $\color{blue}{\text{$\tau_{cf}$-open}}$. But $\mathbb R = \mathbb R \setminus \emptyset =g^{-1}(I) \cup \mathbb R \setminus g^{-1}(J) = $ union of two finite sets. Contradiction.

My question:

- $\color{red}{\text{part in red}}: \ F \in \tau_{cf} \text{ and $F$ is finite $\implies \mathbb R \setminus F$ is finite and $\mathbb (\mathbb R \setminus F) \cup F = \mathbb R =$ finite}$. Looks like a contradiction to me.
- $\color{green}{\text{part in green}}:$ The expression in green implies $\mathbb R \setminus f^{-1}(F)$ is countable. How do we know this subset of reals is countable? It's treated as something self-evident, but it's not obvious to me.
- $\color{blue}{\text{part in blue}}:$ The expression in blue implies $\mathbb R \setminus g^{-1}(I)$ is finite. How do we know this? Again, not at all obvious to me :)

Can someone, please, comment on these? Thanks.

Comment: Part in red: Note that $F$ is not open in $\tau_{cf}$: it’s **closed**.  I don’t understand what you think the contradiction is: you don’t get to say its complement is finite. Its complement is **open**, so its complement is either empty or has finite complement; that is, $F$ is either $\mathbb{R}$ or finite, exactly as stated.

Comment: Part in green: same problem. No, it does not imply the complement is countable; it implies the complement is open, so the **complement** has countable complement.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, I am using the following definition: https://ibb.co/4254GwH Am I parsing it wrong?

Comment: What you seem to be getting confused on is that the set $F$ is **closed**. That means that $A=\mathbb{R}\setminus F$ is open. That means that it is $A$ that has finite complement or is empty. That is, $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ is finite or $A$ is empty; these correspond to $F$ being finite or $F=\mathbb{R}$. You cannot deduce that $\mathbb{R}\setminus F$ is finite, because $F$ is not given as open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\color{red}{\text{red: } } $The definitions do have these exceptions or else they would not be topologies:

- In the cofinite topology of a set $X$, the closed sets are precisely the finite sets -- as well as $X$ itself (because in every topology, $\emptyset$ and $X$ are closed)
- In the cocountable topology of a set $X$, the closed sets are precisely the countable sets -- as well as $X$ itself (because in every topology, $\emptyset$ and $X$ are closed)

$\color{green}{\text{green: } } $Note that the argument uses closed sets, not open sets, hence finite/countable sets, not cofinite/cocountable sets.

$\color{blue}{\text{blue: } } $ Open follows from continuity.

Answer (score 5):

The red part is not a contradiction, it's the **definition** of the cofinite topology: the only **closed** sets are the finite ones (including $\emptyset$) and $\Bbb R$ (because it has to be closed in any topology). The open sets are the **complements** of these. So if $F$ is closed, it's *not* the case that $\Bbb R\setminus F$ is finite, but $\Bbb R\setminus F$ is open, but the proof doesn't want to discuss open sets, but show continuity just using closed sets.

In green we just use that that a finite set is countable so **closed** in $T_{cc}$.

in blue: the inverse image of open is open (by continuity) and the only non-empty open sets in the cofinite topology are the ones with a finite complement.